# how to save data from sent javascript extension through servlet and stored in couchdb database?

Tags: servlets

I am making an extension by which user can select text on the webpage and click on extension, this will save the selected content in COUCHDB database.The selecting of text is done in javascript extension and data is saved through servlet. But after connecting all the things the error is dispalyed on extension as: ERROR SAVING:NOT FOUND. I have pasted the files used. Also, if I am running the same file popup.js(extension files) with wamp server after making a its server file like servlet, it is running well. I think there is some problem in servlet code, please post your suggestions.
thanks in advance

Servlet code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;
    import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
    import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws           

    ServletException, IOException
        {
            doPost(req,res);
        }
            @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws 

    ServletException, IOException
        {
            res.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
                    InputStream requestBodyInput = req.getInputStream();    
                  String s1=req.getParameter("title");
                  String s2=req.getParameter("url");
                  String s3=req.getParameter("summary");
                  String s4=req.getParameter("tags");
                   savedata(s1,s2,s3,s4);

        }


   public String savedata(String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4)throws IllegalArgumentException
         {

       Session dbSession;
        Database db;
        Document newdoc;
        final String title="title";
        final String url="url";
        final String summary="summary";
        final String tags="tags";

        String dbName = "checkurl";
        dbSession = new Session("localhost",5984);

        db = dbSession.getDatabase(dbName);
            newdoc = new Document();
            /*Map for list of properties for the new document*/

              /*Map for list of properties for the new document*/
              Map<String , String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();

              properties.put(title, s1);
              properties.put(url, s2);
              properties.put(summary, s3);
              properties.put(tags, s4);

              newdoc.putAll(properties);

              /*Saving the new document in the 'student' database */
              db.saveDocument(newdoc);  
              return null;



         }
}




 Extension file: popup.js



     // This callback function is called when the content script has been 
    // injected and returned its results
    function onPageInfo(o)  { 
        document.getElementById('title').value = o.title; 
        document.getElementById('url').value = o.url; 
        document.getElementById('summary').innerText = o.summary; 

    } 

    // Global reference to the status display SPAN
    var statusDisplay = null;

    // POST the data to the server using XMLHttpRequest
    function addBookmark() {
        // Cancel the form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        // The URL to POST our data to
        var postUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/examples/NewServlet';

        // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

        // Prepare the data to be POSTed
        var title = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('title').value);
        var url = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('url').value);
        var summary = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('summary').value);
        var tags = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('tags').value);

        var params = 'title=' + title + 
                       '&url=' + url + 
                     '&summary=' + summary +
                     '&tags=' + tags;

        // Replace any instances of the URLEncoded space char with +
        params = params.replace(/%20/g, '+');

        // Set correct header for form data 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        // Handle request state change events
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            // If the request completed
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                statusDisplay.innerHTML = '';
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    // If it was a success, close the popup after a short delay
                    statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saved!';
                    window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
                } else {// Show what went wrong
                    statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Error saving: ' + xhr.statusText;
                }
            }
        };

        // Send the request and set status
        xhr.send(params);
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
    }

    // When the popup HTML has loaded
    window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
        // Handle the bookmark form submit event with our addBookmark function
        document.getElementById('addbookmark').addEventListener('submit', addBookmark);
        // Cache a reference to the status display SPAN
        statusDisplay = document.getElementById('status-display');
        // Call the getPageInfo function in the background page, injecting content_script.js 
        // into the current HTML page and passing in our onPageInfo function as the callback
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getPageInfo(onPageInfo);
    });
```

Comment: did you find the soln?